# how to retrieve data on n text boxes according to the selection of drop down box in php

Tags: javascript, php

When I select 1 from the drop down box 1 text box will appear on he screen, if 2 is selected 2 boxes will appear etc.. if I enter some values on the text box, the values can't retrieve when the form is  submitted. please provide the code for retrieving the data from the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like this

```
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <button id="submit-button">get textarea data</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const rootEl = document.getElementById("root");
    const textareaEl = document.createElement("textarea");
    const buttonEl = document.getElementById("submit-button");

    buttonEl.addEventListener("click", retrieveTextareaData);
    rootEl.appendChild(textareaEl);
    rootEl.appendChild(submitButtonEl);

    function retrieveTextareaData(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const textAreaContent = textareaEl.value;

      console.log(textAreaContent);
    }
  </script>
```